# C# Count the number of items in a Dictionary where the string value contains a certain string

Tags: c#, dictionary

This is just a quick question as to if there is an easier/quicker way to get the count of all elements in a dictionary where the string value contains a certain string. I.e. all the elements stored where the value has "test" in it.
Obviously, I can loop through all elements and get the value, then do a check to see if it contains the value, and if it does increment a counter, but I was just wondering if there was a easier/quicker way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "easier" and "quicker".  You can write a one liner with Linq, but it will still iterate through all the items.

Answer (score 7):

You could use LINQ, that would not be quicker in terms of CPU cycles but more readable:

```
int count = dict.Count(kv => kv.Value.Contains("test"));
```

if you want to ignore the case you have to use `IndexOf`:

```
int count = dict.Count(kv => kv.Value.IndexOf("test",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

You could also use `dict.Values.Count(...)`. Using the dictionary as source collection has just the advantage that you have   the key and the value if you need both.

Comment: or dict.Values.Count(v => v.Contains("test"));

Comment: and yes it is: loop, check, count. Its just nicer syntax

Comment: @fix_likes_coding: Yes, LINQ just hides the loops and makes your code better to read.

Comment: Using `.Values` has a minor performance advangate and a greater, but more subjective, notational advantage of reflecting the fact that the values is all you care about here more explicitly.

Comment: @JonHanna: how large is the performance advantage and what causes it? However, i've preferred to use the dictionary since many people aren't aware of the fact that you can use them directly as source for LINQ queries. Of course you'll lose the fast lookup capabilities when enumerating it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter very minor as I say. It comes from how the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ValueCollection` can just ignore the keys entirely and enumerate through the values rather than grabbing two different values. If the key type is a large struct the impact is larger, but still minor. My only reason for favouring it would be that it puts the thought "we only care about values from here on" into your code at the beginning rather than the thought "and now we care about the value" when considering each key-value pair.

Comment: @JonHanna: thanks. Often i find myself missing the key even if i intially thought that i'm only interested in the values (or vice-versa), if only for debugging or logging purposes.   But again, the sole reason for using it was to prevent that some people lookup the values to find a specific one and then lookup the keys to find the corresponding key. I have seen such code.